# Pandas .loc() method using "not" and "in" operators

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame and I want to remove some rows if their value is not equal to some values that I have stored in a list.

So I have a list variable stating the values of objects I want to keep:

```py
allowed_values = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
```

And I am attempting to remove rows from my dataframe if a certain column does not contain 1 of the `allowed_values`. At first I was using a `for` loop and `if` statement like this:

```py
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row["Type"] not in allowed_values:
        # drop the row, was about to find out how to do this, but then I found out about the `.loc()` method and thought it would be better to use this.
```

So using the `.loc()` method, I can do something like this to only keep objects that have a `Type` value equal to `value1`:

```py
df = df.loc[df["Type"] == "value1"]
```

But I want to keep all objects that have a `Type` in the `allowed_values` list. I tried to do this:

```py
df = df.loc[df["Type"] in allowed_values]
```

but this gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I would expect this to still work as using the `in` or a combination of `not in` operators still results in a boolean, so I'm not sure why the `.loc()` method doesn't like these operators.

What exactly is wrong with using `in` or `not` operators in the `.loc()` method and how can I create a logical statment that will drop rows if their `Type` value is not in the `allowed_values` list?

**EDIT**: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o) question asking about the same error I got and the answer was that you need to use bitwise operators only (e.g. `==`, `!=`, `&`, `|`, etc) and `not` and `in` are not bitwise operators and require something called "truth-values". So I think the only way to get the functionality I want is to just have a lengthy bitwise logical operator, something like:

```py
df = df.loc[(df["Type"] == "value1") | (df["Type"] == "value2") | (df["Type"] == "value3")]
```

Is there no other way to check each value is in the `allowed_values` list? This would make my code a lot neater (I have more than 3 values in the list, so this is a lengthy line).

Comment: Thanks @slothrop, someone else added an answer, but this was still what I was looking (and that question tells me how to do NOT IN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
allowed_values = ['White', 'Green', 'Red']
df = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['White', 'Black', 'Green', 'White']})
df = df[df['color'].isin(allowed_values)]
df

   color
0  White
2  Green
3  White
```

If you must use `.loc` then you can use:

```
df = df.loc[df['color'].isin(allowed_values)]
```

Comment: And yes I don't even need to use the `.loc()` method, thanks for that too!